# How to keep two tables in sync

Tags: javascript, web-services

I want to keep a table in sync between various clients and I'm almost sure that this is a thing but I don't know the name of the service I need.

User A and user B are visiting the same web page and the page shows a table with data queried from a DB.

User B inserts a new record or updates a record.

**Is there a way for me to update the table for user A without the need for user A to manually refresh?** I can use pub/sub but it's some work and I was wondering if there is a simpler way...

**Merci!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De rien!

Whatever simpler way you choose, you will need to update the values dynamically through JavaScript. So as user B has changed the record, and you have used pub/sub, or the data is on firestore, or whatever database you are using; once the events or query listeners have fired in the client of user A, you simply update the value in user A's client, through JavaScript, so that user A gets to see the new change.

You may appreciate [Firebase Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore) that has this synchronizing feature "auto-embedded". You will need to set [snapshot changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) and you are good. One thing is your table data has to be accessed in a NoSQL method, that is as collections and documents since that is how data is structured in Firestore.